# Is it possible to use the inList Filter to filter a FeatureView in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: list, filtering, google-earth-engine

I am trying to filter a FeatureView dataset in GEE using the Javascript code space. The code below works

```
var wdpa = ui.Map.FeatureViewLayer("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons_FeatureView")

wdpa.setVisParams({
  color:  'greenyellow',
  rules:[{
    filter: ee.Filter.inList("WDPAID",[1250]).not(),
    isVisible: false,
    }]
});

Map.add(wdpa)
```

But as soon as I add an extra element to the list it fails with the following message **Layer error: [1250, 555622048] cannot be cast to a double for property WDPAID.**

```
var wdpa = ui.Map.FeatureViewLayer("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons_FeatureView")

wdpa.setVisParams({
  color:  'greenyellow',
  rules:[{
    filter: ee.Filter.inList("WDPAID",[1250,555622048]).not(),
    isVisible: false,
    }]
});

Map.add(wdpa)
```

Any help would be much apprieciated. I have tried casting the list but it doesnt seem to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone and not sure if its the best solution but I built an expression and used that

```
var wdpa = ui.Map.FeatureViewLayer("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons_FeatureView")

var arr = [1250,555622048]

var query = '';
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var max = ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(i, arr.length -1);
  var substring = ee.Algorithms.If(max,'WDPAID == ' + arr[i],'WDPAID == ' + arr[i] + ' || ');
  query += substring.getInfo();
}
wdpa.setVisParams({
  color:  'greenyellow',
  rules:[{
    filter: ee.Filter.expression(query).not(),
    isVisible: false,
    }]
});

Map.add(wdpa)
```